# CKeditor plugin closing on clicking an overlay

Tags: ckeditor5

I have created a plugin in CKeditor-5 for FontAwesome 6 icons, in this plugin i have option to color icons as well, so on an input click i am opening an overlay from which i can select a color, but as soon as i click this overlay plugin is closing, i want to prevent this from happening, any solutions?

> link to github repository -
> https://github.com/atulsilori/fontawsome6.git